# Connecting Google Cloud Build to Private Endpoints

Tags: mongodb-atlas, google-cloud-build

I have a VPC network and that network has a private endpoint for my database connection. All servers are able to connect to the database without fail. However, once I turn on a cloud build (in a private pool, in the same VPC network), the cloud build system cannot seem to find or connect to my private endpoint to build out the static pages of the website.

Do I need to setup a special VPN? how can I even begin to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Have you looked at https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/connect-build#private-ip and https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/private-pools/set-up-private-pool-to-use-in-vpc-network#gcloud ?

Comment: I have setup the private pool in my VPC, I have not trying the connecting article - would that apply to mongodb-atlas as well? I don't think it does.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly yes, you have to set up a VPN as described in that [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/accessing-private-gke-clusters-with-cloud-build-private-pools) (for GKE but the principle in the same)

In fact, you need to have a look to the underlying architecture.

- From Cloud Build private pool to your VPC, a peering is created
- From your VPC to Cloud SQL private IP (or GKE Private control plane, or mongo-db Atlas), a peering is created

Therefore the network architecture is the following

```
Cloud Build private Pool -> peering -> VPC -> peering -> Cloud SQL private IP
```

One of limitation of VPC peeing on GCP is the non-transitivity ( if A -> B and B -> C, then A can't reach C)

That's why a VPN is a (non glorious) solution

Comment: This works with a VPN. The non-transitivity makes things difficult. However making a VPN work, is not that easy. BGP sessions, etc. complicate things quite a bit.

Comment: Agree, things are horrible, and cost expensive. However, PSC, private service connect, should be soon compliant with CLoud SQL and should avoid that weird architecture.